# Is there a way to associate Specflow+Runner test cases with Azure Test plan?

Tags: specflow, runner, specrun

We are looking for some solutions around associating our automation test cases with Azure test plan with Specflow+Runner.

Tech stack:

- Visual Studio 2017/19
- .Net Framework 4.8
- Specflow 3.1.97
- SpecRun.Runner/SpecRun.Specflow 3.2.31

We have recently started using Specflow+ Runner and previously we were using Specflow with Xunit. When I am trying to associate a test case in Visual Studio, we are facing below issue. This used to work perfectly when we were using Xunit.
[image]

If you have come across this situation and have got a solution or workaround, please do share with us. Basically we are looking at something that can tag our automation test cases in test plan.

Below is the link that provides information about associating test cases, which worked fine for us till we were using XUnit.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/associate-automated-test-with-test-case?view=azure-devops

Please do let me know in case you need any further information on this from my side. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly the association with test cases when using the SpecFlow+ Runner is not possible out of the box. There is no possibility to extend this behavior we are aware of.

But you could use [SpecSync](https://www.specsolutions.eu/specsync/). It synchronizes your Scenarios into Test Cases and also provides the test execution results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Azure test API's and add them in the Hooks with the correct order so test runs can be created, test results can be updated during test runs. You just need to understand how Azure test API's work and add the test case ID's to your scenario names.